How to separate the x in $ e^{-2Cbx} $ from the variable b.
Here is my problem.
I have a set of values that the variable $s$ represents the size of:
$$ f(x) = e^{Cx^2} * \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{s} ae^{-2bCx}e^{Cb^2} $$
$C$ and $a$ are constants while $b$ is the value of the item $n$ in the set mentioned above. The problem is in the term $ e^{-2bCx} $. I need a way to isolate the $x$ and the $b$ from each other in such a way that the term that contains $b$ only has other constants (same for the $x$ term).
For example: $$ e^{x+b} $$ can be written as $$ e^xe^b $$ which I would consider separated.
The whole point of this is so that only constants and b are present inside the summation so I can take the x term out of the summation. Any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated.
